# Delphi StrToInt on Hex String WORD, UShort, 16 Bit hex fails

Tags: delphi, hex

I currently use.

Here is a few outputs I formatted them they were all together like this.

> E14802000003FA00014C0000031501A8

```
  currentAttackCount := StrToInt('$' + Copy(CurHex, 17, 4));
  Log('Packet = ' + CurHex + ' Count = ' + IntToStr(currentAttackCount) + ' STR = ' + '$' + Copy(CurHex, 17, 4));
```

Formatted outputs

> Packet = E1 48 02 00 00 03 FA 00 [01 4C] 00 00 03 15 01 A8 [Count = 76] [STR = $014C]
>  
>   Packet = E1 48 02 00 00 03 FA 00 [01 4D] 00 00 03 15 02 26 [Count = 77] [STR = $014D]
>   Packet = E1 48 02 00 00 03 FA 00 [01 4F] 00 00 03 15 02 26 [Count = 79] [STR = $014F]

As you can see the `STR`
output which is `STR = $014C`
code: `'STR = ' + '$' + Copy(CurHex, 17, 4));`

Now if you look at the `StrToInt`

```
currentAttackCount := StrToInt('$' + Copy(CurHex, 17, 4));
```

It's pretty much the same as `STR` so shouldn't `$014C` aka `0x014C` be represented as `332` instead of `76`

The `76` seems to come from the `$4C` aka `0x4C` of the `$014C` why does it ignore the first `2` Hex Characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I think I figured it out.

```
  `currentAttackCount: Byte;`
```

I increased it to

```
  currentAttackCount: Word;
```

hopefully that would solve the problem.. missed it because it's a global variable and there is soo much code.

Comment: Why do you use global variables? And why do you use `Byte` and `Word`? `Integer` is the native integer type and is what you should use for counts.

Comment: I needed `0..65535` so why not? it works now and `0xFFFF` shouldn't really use more then that anyways.

Comment: What happens when you run a for loop 0 to count-1 with unsigned loop variable? What's the harm in using Integer. Just use it for all counts and loops and forget about thinking if the type is large enough. What's to be gained with your approach? It's what led to this question. And you've really got to give up global vars too. They lead to pain too.

Comment: The rest of us use Integer for counts and shun global variables. Feel free to do it your way if you think it's better.